# Upload SSL files to Google Cloud Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I would like to upload my SSL certificates to my Google Cloud Platform instance. 
I have been trying to just upload a simple text file in order to test the procedure. No luck....

I tried with my domain name

```
scp  ~/sslfiles/test.txt . root@mywebsite.com:/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/test.txt
```

I get an error: Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection

I also tried with my IP

```
scp  ~/sslfiles/test.txt . root@2xx.3xx.4xx.5xx:/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/test.txt
```

I get an error:
ssh: connect to host 2xx.3xx.4xx.5xx port 22: Connection refused
lost connection

What are the correct commands to upload the file and set the owner to root:root?
I am using OSX. The test file is in a /sslfiles directory in my user folder. My "bitnami-gce-bitnami-xyzxyzxyz.pem" key file is in the .ssl directory in my user folder.

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here,

You will need to specify the absolute path to the `bitnami-gce-bitnami-xyzxyzxyz.pem` file to be used in the `scp` command using option `-i`. Also, using root user to connect through SSH is disabled by default for security reasons. Because of that, you will need to send files using `bitnami` for the username to a location with writable permission for this user (e.g. /home/bitnami) and then use `sudo` utility to move files with higher privileges or you can enable root login if you prefer.

You can find more information about how to connect to the server through SSH in our wiki entry at https://wiki.bitnami.com/Google_Cloud_Platform/Servers#How_to_connect_to_the_server_through_SSH.3f and how to upload files to the server with SFTP at https://wiki.bitnami.com/Google_Cloud_Platform/Servers#How_to_upload_files_to_the_server_with_SFTP.3f

Best regards,

Gonzalo

Answer (score 0):

First you need to verify the ownership of the domain. You can do this on Google Cloud going to...

> App Engine > Settings > Custom Domains